# I can't call the COM interface when writing a C# program

Tags: c#, com, interface

Does anyone ever using COM interface in C#?
I add a reference and find it contains interfaces. I don't know how to call the method of a specified interface.
Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: You'll need you read the documentation of the COM API and before you can call a method, you'll need to create or get an instance of a COM class

Answer (score 3):

Sure, people call COM interfaces whenever they must access functionality that is not written in .NET or for which there is no exiting .NET wrapper, but which is exposed through COM.

[This is called COM Interop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Interop).

A common example is using COM interop to work with Word and Excel.

A full explanation would be beyond the scope of a typical Stack Overflow answer.  There's a [tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645712%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to get you started.

If you have specific questions as you start down that path, just post new questions here.

Comment: Thanks @Eric J. I'm looking at the link page you provide~

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a Function or anything like that you can call and that returns a instance to a interface. As example DirectSound uses CreateDirectSound to create IDirectSound interface instance. With that instance you can create IDirectSoundBuffer instances and so on :)

Comment: Yeah, got it~ I'll try to figure it out